# Ionic 3 NavController does not pop the view instead creates a new one

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2, ionic-view

The `ionViewDidLoad` function seem to get called twice, which is causing multiple views being created of AddressPage. I have debugged this and it looks like whenever data is updated the new instance of view gets created. This behaviour seems to happen only when I use fireabse to save the address. If I comment out the code to save the address new view is not created and app navigates to previous screen. 
Any way to avoid this?

I have tried `ViewCotnroller.dismiss()` and `NavController.pop()` inside saveAddress method  but non seem to avoid creation of new view.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#1572b5');
    });

  }

}
```

Home Page

```
import {NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: 
     FirebaseProvider) {
  }

 //navigate to different view
 navigate(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddressPage, {address:newAddress});
 }

}
```

Address Page

```
import {NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-address',
  templateUrl: 'address.html'
})
export class AddressPage {

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: 
    FirebaseProvider, private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.addressKey = this.navParams.get('key');
   }

   ionViewDidEnter(){
      //load some data from server
   }

   saveAddress(){
     //save data to server
     this.firebaseProvider.saveAddress(newAddress);
     //move back
     this.navCtrl.pop();

   }

}
```

Firebase provider that uses AngularFireDatabase

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseProvider {

  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) { }


  saveAddress(address) {
     this.afd.list('/addresses').push(address);
  }

  updateAddress(key,dataToUpdate){
     return this.afd.list('addresses').update(key,dataToUpdate);
  }

}
```

I have also tried this but it has the same issue.

```
 this.firebaseProvider.saveAddress(newAddress).then(result => {
       // loadingSpinner.dismiss();
        this.navCtrl.pop();
      });

this.firebaseProvider.updateAddress(this.addressKey, updateItems)
        .then(() => {
         //   loadingSpinner.dismiss();
            this.navCtrl.pop()
     });
```

The HTML of save button

```
  <button type="button" ion-button full color="primary-blue" (click)='saveAddress()'>Save</button>
```

Comment: Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Could you re-produce your problem at stackblitz.com?

Comment: @duannx I tried to setup the project but it has too many dependencies to resolve. Any other way I can share my code?

Comment: If you can re-produce your problem, that mean you know where your problem come from, no need to add all dependencies and pages. In some case, when you do it, you can find the answer your self.

Comment: It needs firebase setup, that is the tricky part.

Comment: please show your save button html code may be you are using arrow function on html

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj added html snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like unsubscribing to the subscribers fixes the issue. The HomePage view had subscribers which were not unsubscribed. I added the Observable Subscriptions into the array and unsubscribed as per code below.

```
  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.subscriptions.forEach(item=>{
      item.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the push method returs a promise with the result of the action.  I would change the save method like this:

```
saveAddress(address) { 
    return this.afd.list('/addresses').push(address); 
}
```

Then in the controller I’d change it in this way:

```
saveAddress(){ 
    //save data to serve
    this.firebaseProvider.saveAddress(newAddress).then(result => { 
    //do yours validations
    this.navCtrl.pop();
    });
}
```

With thos you tide up the navigation of the page to the result of the Firebase execution. Give it a try to this approach and let me know if it didn’t work, anyway I would use oninit to load data only once as I guess you wanna do it rather than ionViewDidEnter.

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work. See my updated code above. ionViewDidEnter should be fine as per ionic doc the problem is it is executing twice as view is being created again after hitting save button.

Comment: Have you checked the views stack? Inspect the navCtrl to see which is the next view ib the stack.

Comment: I’m sure you already read this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component . I can’t find in your code how do you inject the navController? In that link you will find how to pass the root nav controller to a child view. I’m not sure because I only have part of your code to analyze but I guess the problem is related the way you are doing the navigation.

Comment: I am using simple push and pop as per documentation. I have updated the code